# What Node JS modules or framework should you use to build a dashboard SQL 2008 server data?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2008, user-interface, interface

I'm pretty familiar with NodeJS by now and have programmed a couple apps.

However, this new project is confusing me. I'm basically to tap into a MSSQL server that has over 1000 tables and each table connects to each other through join statements.

I need to pretty much create an analytics dashboard that gives execs an overview of how their project is going. I only have READ ONLY access to the MS-SQL database.

What framework/module would you recommend - what would you use if you had to do this project? Does not have to be a web based reporting tool but that would be ideal.

Comment: https://npms.io/search?q=SQL+Server

Comment: Thank you for  your answer @JasonLivesay - I've tried searching and googling around. There's a lot of choices but I was just wondering what the wisest approach to this is - from someone who's possibly done this before.